# JOIN vs UNION vs IN() - big tables and many WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL 5.5 and I have 3 tables created for testing:

1. **attributes** (entity_id, cid, aid, value) - indexes: ALL
2. **items** (entity_id, price, currency) - indexes: entity_id
3. **rates** (currency_from, currency_to, rate) - indexes: NONE

I need to count the results for specified conditions (search by attributes) and select X rows ordered by some column. 
**The query should support searching in item attributes (attributes table).**

I have a query like this at first:

```
SELECT i.entity_id, i.price * COALESCE(r.rate, 1) AS final_price 
FROM items i
JOIN attributes a ON a.entity_id = i.entity_id
LEFT JOIN rates r ON i.currency = r.currency_from AND r.currency_to = 'EUR'
WHERE a.cid = 4 AND ( (a.aid >= 10 AND a.value > 2000) OR (a.aid <= 10 AND a.value > 5) )
HAVING final_price BETWEEN 0 AND 9000
ORDER BY final_price DESC
LIMIT 20
```

but it's quite slow on big tables. The where conditions can be bigger (even to 30 params) and use `CAST(a.value as SIGNED)` to use `BETWEEN` sometimes (for range values).

For example:

```
SELECT 
      i.entity_id, 
      i.price * COALESCE(r.rate, 1) AS final_price 
   FROM 
      attributes a 
         JOIN items i
            ON a.entity_id = i.entity_id 
         LEFT JOIN rates r 
            ON i.currency = r.currency_from 
            AND r.currency_to = 'EUR'
   WHERE 
      a.cid = 4 AND ( 
(a.aid = 10 AND CAST(a.value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2014) 
OR (a.aid = 121 AND CAST(a.value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 40 AND 60) 
OR (a.aid = 45 AND CAST(a.value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 770 AND 1500) 
OR (a.aid = 95 AND CAST(a.value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 12770 AND 15500) 
OR (a.aid = 98 AND a.value = 'some value') 
OR (a.aid = 199 AND a.value = 'some another value') 
OR (a.aid = 102 AND a.value = 1)
OR (a.aid = 112 AND a.value = 42) ) 
   GROUP BY
      i.entity_id
   HAVING 
      COUNT(i.entity_id) = 7 
         AND final_price BETWEEN 0 AND 9000
   ORDER BY 
      final_price DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

I group by COUNT() equal to 7 (number of attributes to search), because I need to find items with all these attributes.

EXPLAIN for the base query (the first one):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL entity_id,value NULL    NULL    NULL    379999  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  i   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   testowa.a.entity_id 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  r   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2
```

I read many topics about comparing `UNION` vs `JOIN` vs `IN()` and the best results gives the second option, but it's too slow all the time.

Is there any way to get better performance here? Why is it so slow?
Should I think about moving some logic (split this query to 3 small) to backend (php/ror) code?

Comment: You don't seem to have indexes on the columns used for the `join`s.  That is the place to start with optimization.  But if you have a whole system generating a bunch of queries, the problem is probably too big for a forum such as this.

Comment: I added indexes for currency and currency_to/currency_from and now ~1.3535.

Comment: I have the queries for search only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure your query slightly and have the attributes table first
and then joined to the items.  Also, I would have a covering index on the 
items table via (entity_id, price) and an index on your attributes table 
ON (cid, aid, value, entity_id), and your rates table index 
ON (currency_from, currency_to, rate).  This way, all are covering indexes
and the engine won't need to go to the raw data pages to get the data, it can
pull it from the indexes it is already using for the joining / criteria.

```
SELECT 
      i.entity_id, 
      i.price * COALESCE(r.rate, 1) AS final_price 
   FROM 
      attributes a 
         JOIN items i
            ON a.entity_id = i.entity_id 
         LEFT JOIN rates r 
            ON i.currency = r.currency_from 
            AND r.currency_to = 'EUR'
   WHERE 
      a.cid = 4 AND ( (a.aid >= 10 AND a.value > 2000) OR (a.aid <= 10 AND a.value > 5) )
   HAVING 
      final_price BETWEEN 0 AND 9000
   ORDER BY 
      final_price DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

So, although this would help the query you have provided, could you show some other where you would have many more criteria conditions... you mentioned it could be as many (or more) than 30.  Looking at more might alter the query slightly.

As for your updated query with multiple criteria, I would then add an IN() clause for all the "aid" values after the "a.cid = 4".  This way, before it has to hit all the "OR" conditions, if it fails on the "aid" not being one you consider, it never has to hit those... such as

```
      a.cid = 4 
   AND a.id in ( 10, 121, 45, 95, 98, 199, 102 )
   AND  ( rest of the complex aid, casting and between criteria )
```

Comment: it takes ~0.21 now. I added more conditions in the question, please look at.

Comment: @deem, revised answer.

Comment: Do you mean add extra IN() statement for aid in addition to the old where statments?

Comment: @deem, yes.  This way, if you have an "aid" value of 3, it will fail the "and a.id in ( .., .. ,.. ,..  )" and never have to get to the rest with all the and/or cast value, and/or cast value, etc... it fails right away and does not have to hit the rest of the criteria.

Comment: I asked to confirm, because it doesn't change the execution time. Maybe, I will see the difference on bigger sets, right?  BTW Do you know any materials to read about parsing SQL queries (in MySQL), to prove your words?

Comment: @deem, no proof, just personal experience